# can't install java

Tags: installation, apt, java, openjdk

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
[sudo] password for paul: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (= 7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libgnome2-0 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libgnomevfs2-0 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libgconf2-4 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: ttf-dejavu-extra but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: did you tried installing it from just software center ?? and what version of ubuntu are you using ??

Answer (score 0):

With my experience with openjdk is not very good (I think it is even worse then Java itself)  so I do not like java at all but if you want to install it I recommend you installing it with this guide

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-oracle-java-jdk-678-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04/